# Aliasing the result of an union

Tags: sql, oracle, union, alias

I have 2 select statements. I union them.

```
select * from t1
union all
select * from t2
```

Can I alias the result? Will something like

```
union all as t3
```

work?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the alias you have in mind?

Comment: @Tim basically there are a lot of tables. I want to union first 2 tables then  2 others or  the result of some union with another table or with a result of another union. All of this might be divided by some other statements.

Comment: Then you might consider using one or more CTEs to keep things organized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly alias the `UNION` query itself:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM t2
) t
```

If you want a way to reuse the `UNION` query, you can consider using a common table expression (CTE):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM t2
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: In the first example SQL, *compels* you to assign a range variable even though you don't actually need it e.g. change `SELECT t.*` to just `SELECT *`, which is a bit silly. The CTE is superior!